# What's meaning of those codes in jquery.validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Here source codes in jquery.validation.js

```
// make sure required is at front
if (data.required) {
    param = data.required;
    delete data.required;
    data = $.extend({
        required: param
    }, data);
}
// make sure remote is at back
if (data.remote) {
    param = data.remote;
    delete data.remote;
    data = $.extend(data, {
        remote: param
    });
}
```

I am puzzled about "front" and "back". Can someone make an example to explain the unexpected result if I delete there codes.

Comment: It is to make sure that the required validation is applied at the beginning and remote is applied at the end

Comment: what do `extend`? it take first param, and add property from second param, so for `required` you get object where first added property would be `required`, and for `remote` you get object where property `remote` would be added last. But i not sure how it helps in validation, i think loop over object properties can be independent from order adding it to object

Comment: as for unexpected result: i think this is somthing like priority for validation.

Comment: @Grundy  I think you may be right. howerver looping order is not always same to appling order.

Comment: @zhenyong, yep, from [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in): _The for...in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, **in arbitrary order**._